# RethinkDB - optimize query that does geolocation, then join, then grouping

Tags: join, geolocation, geospatial, rethinkdb

In my application, I have two tables: one for users (with a geospatial index 'location'), and one for scores that the user has received (secondary index on 'userid').

I'm trying to design a query that pulls the latest scores for the 25 users closest to a specific geographic location. See below:

```
// "location" is a variable that holds r.point(lon, lat)
r
  .table('users')
  .getNearest(location, {index: 'location', maxDist: 500})
  .limit(25)
  .eqJoin(
    r.row('doc')('id'), // the getNearest returns original data inside "doc" object
    r.table('scores'),
    {index: 'userid'})
  .zip()
  .group('userid')
  .max('scoredate')
```

Right now, I have ~40k users in the users table and ~100k scores in the scores table. The average query time for this operation is 50ms-100ms, and I'm trying to improve that as much as possible.

Can anyone help me optimize this query? I want to make it as fast as possible because the users/scores tables are constantly growing.

Comment: A minor optimization would be to replace the `limit(25)` by adding the `maxResults: 25` optarg to `getNearest`: `.getNearest(location, {index: 'location', maxDist: 500, maxResults: 25})`

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the fastest version of the query I can think of.  If 50-100ms is too high, you might just need faster hardware.  If the speed is fine now but you're worried about it getting slower in the future, I wouldn't worry too much because both operations are indexed so it should scale really well.